# Regularly re-appearing Intermittent 2s freezes (Intel i5, NVidia GF 670, Vertex4 SSD, Win8-64)

Tags: windows-8, freeze

My system is as follows:

- CPU: Intel i5
- GPU: NVidia GeForce GTX 670
- SSD: OCZ Vertex 4

From time to time, usually after prolonged use, my computer starts freezing. It does not crash, nor freeze completely, but behaves weirdly in a very specific pattern:

1. For a second, everything is frozen.

   - if sound is playing, it will give digital artifacts, repeating the last slice (phonetic: trrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr).
   - screen will not change, mouse movements are not shown
2. The next second, everything works fine.

This pattern repeats itself until I reboot.

It is not dependent on an application, if I manage to close everything despite the freezes, the pattern will continue even on the windows desktop.

Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Comment: This sounds like a firmware problem with the SSD device.  Have you updated the firmware to the device?

Comment: I will try that. Can you tell me why you think it's related to the SSD?

Comment: Because of the digital artifacts and repeating sound.

Comment: SSD firmware is already on the latest version.

Comment: I would get the data off of the SSD and backed up onto another disk ASAP. This sounds a lot like a failing drive; the freezes are when it fails to read a sector, and it has to repeatedly retry until it manages to successfully read the data.

Comment: It's been like this for 3 months already (since I got the computer). It works most of the time, and if this problem happens, I simply reboot, and it works again. But I will try to get the drive replaced. Thanks!